# python memory de-allocation: what are the local variables with names like _238 _208

Tags: python

In my python program, locals() lists quite some local var with  names like _238 _208.  What are these local vars?  I didn't create them.

The main library used is numpy.

Are these created by python libs and referenced by some other variables? This is because after gc.collect() these variables are still there.

My program uses lots of memory, I want to free some memory to be able to do more calcs.  These variables with names like _238 _208 use lots of memory, as shown by sys.getsizeof(_238).

I would like to know whether it's safe to free these variables.  Looks like it's not safe to free them by doing _238 = None.  Right?

How to find out which other variables are using a particular variable?  That's another way to re-phrase my question.

Thanks.

Comment: Copy and pasting a closed question will not get it answered. Instead, look at the comments and edit the question so that it is answerable.

Comment: Are you in some REPL like Jupyter notebook or Ipython?

Comment: Note, you cannot manually free memory in python...

Comment: I am in ipython. I believe memory for variables not referenced by other variables can be free by setting it to None and calling gc.collect() (I am not sure this is necessary).  I had been doing this constantly. Without setting var = None, I will get MemoryError. With var = None, I can continue calc which use large memory.

Comment: sample code: do calc on matrixA; matrixA = None; matrixB = numpy_func. Without matrixA = None, 'matrixB = numpy_func' which use lots of memory will throw MemoryError.